# How do I print a PDF file to a printer in landscape from Python?

Tags: python, pdf, printing, matplotlib

I'm using Mac OSX but I need a platform independent method to print a pdf file.
I created a graph in Matplotlib and want to print it to my printer.

I can set the orientation of the canvas to fit a portrait layout with:

```
fig.set_size_inches(  8.27,11.69) # set the figure size in inches
```

but using:

```
fig.set_size_inches( 11.69, 8.27)
```

prints a cropped portrait oriented figure

I found this on another post here:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

printfile='test.pdf'
fig.savefig(printfile)
proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('lpr {f}'.format(f=printfile)))
```

Can anyone help me with the format of the code to set the print orientation to landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen `lpr -o landscape`, but do not have enough experience with it to know if it works for all printers.

Rather than changing orientation while printing, you can do it when generating the image (if it fits with your workflow). The matplotlib [`savefig`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) command allows you to specify saving in landscape orientation, but currently only for postscript. That is not a problem, however, since we can easily convert the postscript file to PDF format. Below is an example.

In Python:

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
plot(x, y)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
savefig('img.eps', orientation='landscape')
```

I left out the canvas size for convenience and brevity.

Now we have a file named `img.eps`. In the shell do the following.

```
epstopdf img.eps
```

Here is what the resulting `img.pdf` file looks like:
[image: Landscape image.]

One downside to keep in mind with this approach is that postscript does not like transparency, so if you want transparency this is not the approach for you. To see what I mean take the matplotlib [patch_collection.py](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/patch_collection.html) example. Replace the `pylab.show()` on the last line with `pylab.savefig('patch.pdf')`, run it, and then look at the resulting PDF file. It will look like the image in the example. If, however, you do `pylab.savefig('patch.eps')`, you will see that the objects are all opaque.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I was able to print the 'Image.eps" file directly using: printfile='img.eps'#'test.pdf'
 plt.savefig('img.eps', orientation='landscape')
 proc=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('lpr {f}'.format(f=printfile)))  How would I execute the epstopdf command  programmatically?

Comment: @user1032355 If you want to do it in the Python code, you can add `import subprocess` and `subprocess.call('epstopdf img.eps', shell=True)`.

Comment: Thanks again David for the clarification. When I run it I get :  :/bin/sh: epstopdf: command not found" on a MAC OSX 10.6.8 but your followup clarified the format of the call to shell.

Comment: @user1032355 It looks like `epstopdf` on my machine was installed with [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/). If you do not need LaTeX, installing MacTeX might be overkill. You can probably also do the conversion with Gimp, Photoshop, ImageMagick, and others, but I have always used `epstopdf` since it just works.

Comment: I'm downloading MacTex now but since I need a cross platform solution I'll stick with what I've got so far. This answer works on a MAC; I'll try it on a Windows system later. I know the lpr option flag changes from 0 to 1 for landscape printing i just don't know the command format...AAAgggh

Comment: @user1032355 you should upvote David answer if it has been useful to you. As the OP, you can do both:upvote and select as the best answer. You will be rewarded :-)

Comment: Unless someone tells me how to use lpr David's answer will be selected. (Thanks for the tip on the upvoting)